# Tabela com rowspan usando array

Tags: php, array, table

Estou com dificuldade para fazer foreach com array, sendo 2 colunas com rowspan e outras 2 colunas mostrando array dos produtos de cada forncedor.
Veja o exemplo abaixo de como deveria ser.

```html
<table class="table" border="1" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Fornecedor</th>
      <th>Produto</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">1</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Representante 1</td>
      <td>bolsa 1</td>
      <td>8,89</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bolsa 2</td>
      <td>4,36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bolsa 3</td>
      <td>5,89</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">2</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Representante 2</td>
      <td>bolsa 1</td>
      <td>1,99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bolsa 2</td>
      <td>1,49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bolsa 3</td>
      <td>2,99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

O array recebido é esse!

```
$array = array(
array(
    'codigo' => '1', 
    'fornecedor' => '   Representante 1', 
    array(
        array(
            'produto' => 'bolsa', 
            'valor' => "8,89"
        ),
        array(
            'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 
            'valor' => "4,36"
        ),
        array(
            'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 
            'valor' => "5,89"
        )
    )
),
array(
    'codigo' => '2', 
    'fornecedor' => '   Representante 2', 
    array(
        array(
            'produto' => 'bolsa', 
            'valor' => "1,99"
        ),
        array(
            'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 
            'valor' => "1,49"
        ),
        array(
            'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 
            'valor' => "    2,99"
        )
    )
)
```

);

Answer (score -2):

Olá, tenta alterar seu array colocando uma chave antes dos produtos, assim vc consegue representar melhor os produtos de determinado fornecedor e iterar sobre ela de forma mais simples.

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'codigo' => '1', 
        'fornecedor' => '   Representante 1', 
        'produtos' => array(
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 1', 
                'valor' => "8,89"
            ),
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 2', 
                'valor' => "4,36"
            ),
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 
                'valor' => "5,89"
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'codigo' => '2', 
        'fornecedor' => '   Representante 2', 
        'produtos' => 
        array(
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 1', 
                'valor' => "1,99"
            ),
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 2', 
                'valor' => "1,49"
            ),
            array(
                'produto' => 'bolsa 3', 
                'valor' => "    2,99"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Daí no seu html vc pode fazer algo do tipo

```
<table class="table" border="1" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Fornecedor</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($array as $value) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td rowspan="3">' . $value['codigo'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td rowspan="3">' . $value['fornecedor'] . '</td>';

          $produtos = $value['produtos'];
          $produto1 = array_shift($produtos);

          echo '<td>' . $produto1['produto'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $produto1['valor'] . '</td>';              
          echo '</tr>';

          foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
              echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>' . $produto['produto'] . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $produto['valor'] texto em negrito. '</td>';              
              echo '</tr>';                 
          }        
    }
    ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
```